# Factorising a spacial polynomial

Tags: factoring

I have to factorise $2(x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7)$. It seems that there a very simple expression to which simply this polynomial.

The only thing I found so far is $2 x^2 (1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5)$. Can you explain to me in  details how to factorise this even more? If so, is there a general rule for such similar polynomial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ 2x^2(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5) $

$ 2x^2(1(1+x)+x^2(1+x)+x^4(1+x)) $

$ 2x^2(1+x^2+x^4)(1+x) $

$ 2x^2(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)(1+x) $

Hope this help you

Edit: Here's how $ (1+x^2+x^4) $ can be factorized to $ (x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1) $

$ x^4+x^2+1 $

$ =(x^2)^2+2(x^2)(1)+1^2−x^2$

$ =(x^2+1)^2−x^2$

$ =(x^2+1−x)(x^2+1+x)$

Comment: @Leo if you have any problem in how I moved from $ (1+x^2+x^4) $ to $ (x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)  $  do tell in comment. I will tell you how I did so

Comment: If you can develop at lot, it might help. I am not very familiar with that at all.

Comment: @Leo I have explained that. Pls do tell in comment if you have understood it or if you have any doubt. Pls don't hesitate to ask any other doubt

Answer (score 1):

$x^6 -1 = (x-1)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)$

so all complex $6$-th roots of unity except $1$ are roots of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)$, group them by conjugate pair and you have a factorisation over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: It seems an interesting approach, but I am not familiar with it. Are you up to develop this theory a bit more so I can understand? Can you relate that to some sort of theorem?

Comment: @Leo you can start by dividing out $x+1$ for the root -1, and then write down the other four roots of unity from basic complex numbers theory (easy in polar form).

Comment: I am not familiar with root of unity. That's why I wanted you to explain to me how you did it

Comment: @Leo solve $z^6 = 1$ over $\Bbb C$. We get $z = e^{i\frac{2\pi}{6}}$ and its multiples, etc. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).

Comment: It might be very kind of you if you can explicit that in your answer. I will accept your answer if you can do it.

Comment: @Leo That Wikipedia entry also gives the solution $(x+1)(x^2 +x +1)(x^2- x+1)$

Comment: It might just be interesting for the site to have a full and clean answer. Just take few lines to explain it a bit more using the theory of root of unity.

Answer (score 0):

$$2(x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7)$$

$$2x^2(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)$$

$$2x^2\frac{x^6-1}{x-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$x^2+x^3=x^2(1+x)$

$x^4+x^5=x^4(1+x)$

You can continue...